# How do you capture the output of a closed tmux session or keep the session open after program exits?

Tags: tmux

if I do this:

```
tmux new-session -d -s test ls
```

is there a way to keep the session open after `ls` exits?

I would like to get the output later with this

```
tmux capture-pane -pt test
```

the same way that I can if I have a session that stays open like this

```
tmux new-session -d -s test "tail -f testfile.txt"
```

Or is there another way to capture the output of a session that already existed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to create the session without a specific command, and then call the command later. For instance:

```
tmux new-session -d -s test
tmux send-keys -t test "ls" Enter
tmux capture pane -t test -p
```

This is an odd use of tmux and it seems like `nohup ls &>>~/mylog.out &` might better match your goal.

Comment: because I am using it with ffmpeg, and needed to send a 'q' to make the program stop.  I think you can send a ctrl+c now, but the original blog post I followed used tmux and send 'q', so easiest just to keep using tmux. Only problem was it didn't show the output when it failed, but your solution works great.

Comment: You can always stop any command running from the terminal with ctrl-c. Some other possible options to consider: using `timeout` if this is a timed command; using `bg` and `fg`; actually connecting to the tmux session and manually typing things and seeing the logs; using `nohup` as described and killing with `ps`. That being said, if my answer worked, you should accept it (click green checkmark by it) so that others know this question is resolved without having to click into it and read the whole thing.

Comment: I think you are meant to wait a day or two before accepting an answer, especially when there are probably more possibilities.  I already upvoted your answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers Waiting is not a requirement unless you are attempting to answer your own question, but you are right that you have no obligation to accept my answer if you feel it is not good enough.

Comment: It's good enough.  It totally fixed my problem, but I usually wait anyhow.

Answer (score 3):

`tmux` has an option `remain-on-exit` that I use to retain a command's output when the process exits prematurely.

If you need to set this option prior to the existence of the target session (which seems to be your case), then you'll have to set the option globally for the target server.

If you need to set this option prior to the existence of the target server (which may possibly be your case), then you'll have to create an empty server first before creating the session like so:

```sh
tmux start-server \; \
  set-option -g remain-on-exit on \; \
  new-session -d -s "test" ls
tmux capture-pane -pt "test"
```

---

Another option to keep the pane open actually comes from Windows. Just add a final `read` command at the end of your shell commands:

```
tmux new-session -d -s "test" "ls; read"
```

Or to wait only if the preceding command exited with a non-zero (error) status:

```
tmux new-session -d -s "test" "ls || read"
```

The session will close gracefully by sending it an EOF (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>) or EOL (<kbd>Enter</kbd>), or forcefully with `tmux kill-session ...`.

---

Also, if the example in your question isn't just hypothetical, then all of this seems a bit overkill to capture the output of `ls`. Just use file redirection:

```
ls > capture
```